# Error (invalid_client_id ) from Uber API when authenticating with omniauth-uber

Tags: omniauth, uber-api

I get 'error=invalid_client_id' from Uber when I try to authenticate using the omniauth-uber gem on localhost. I registered my app with Uber and have triple checked my clientID. Is it possible that it is related to me being on localhost and uber not recognizing my app for that?

config/initializer/omniauth.rb file (i've specified my secret key in .env):

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :uber, ENV['UBER_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['UBER_CLIENT_SECRET'], :scope => 'profile,history'
end
```

The snippet from the view that makes the request.

```
<div id="sign-in">
  <%= link_to "Sign in with Uber", "/auth/uber" %>
</div>
```

The Url that I have specified in the uber app registration under the authentication section:

Redirect URL: https://localhost:3000/auth/uber/callback

Origin URI: https://localhost:3000/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by changing my uber app urls from HTTPS to HTTP. I then also removed the ENV from my omniauth.rb file and put the secret key directly in it:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :uber, 'UBER_CLIENT_ID', 'UBER_CLIENT_SECRET', :scope => 'profile,history'
end
```